# special copy (maybe Robocopy) requierement

Tags: robocopy

I have a special copy (maybe Robocopy) requierement:

I have:

- A source directory (with sub-directories)
- A target directory (with sub-directories)

Both directory structures are nearly the same. But in the target directory there are some newer or additional files. I have to copy files from source to target directory that are *not* newer (or added) in the target directory.

Example:

The file example.doc exists in source and target directory. But the file in the target directory has a newer timestamp (someone worked on this file) and I want *not* to overwrite this file.

The file example2.doc exists in source and target directory. Both files have the same timestamp. In this case, I want to overwrite the file in the tartet directory with the file from the source directory.

Maybe Robocopy is the Tool for this case... I read all the parameters (and there are many :) but I didn't find a solution.

BTW:
This is my first post on stackoverflow :-)

Thank you very much.

Gernot

Comment: Tip for googling: you're trying to perform one-way sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rsync` command with the backup switch, `-b`, with the skip newer files on receiver switch, `-u`, as in the following sequence where the first `rsync` gets the files over, the second refuses to overwrite a newer file on the receiver, and the third `rsync` copies the newer file on the sender to the receiver, backing up the file that has been modified on the receiver as *xv~* before overwriting it with the sender's *xv*.  The location of the file that is moved aside can be controlled, and put in another location with the *--backup-dir=DIR* option.

Of course, you can do all this sync'ing on the same filesystem just as easily.

(Hey!  That's how Carbon Copy Cloner does most of it's magic!  And they charge like $40 for the service...  Alas, I digress...)

```
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ rsync -auvb ~/bin whmcclos@localhost:/tmp
building file list ... done
bin/
bin/days
bin/hide
bin/jedit
bin/mlf
bin/most_recent_file -> most_recent_file.pl
bin/most_recent_file.pl
bin/mplayer
bin/mvim
bin/qvim
bin/sys_config
bin/sys_config.log
bin/tree
bin/try
bin/unhide
bin/xv
bin/zed -> zed.pl
bin/zed.pl

sent 18887050 bytes  received 390 bytes  37774880.00 bytes/sec
total size is 18883599  speedup is 1.00
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ touch /tmp/bin/xv
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ rsync -auvb ~/bin whmcclos@localhost:/tmp
building file list ... done

sent 422 bytes  received 20 bytes  294.67 bytes/sec
total size is 18883599  speedup is 42723.07
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ touch /tmp/bin/xv
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ touch ~/bin/xv
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ rsync -auvb ~/bin whmcclos@localhost:/tmp
building file list ... done
bin/xv

sent 7392 bytes  received 10434 bytes  35652.00 bytes/sec
total size is 18883599  speedup is 1059.33
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ ls /tmp/bin/xv*
/tmp/bin/xv  /tmp/bin/xv~
```

Answer (score 0):

> The file example2.doc exists in source and target directory. Both files have 
>   the same timestamp. In this case, I want to overwrite the file in the tartet 
>   directory with the file from the source directory.

The relavent command line switch for this is:

```
/IS      Include Same files.
```

> **Note:** Using the /IS switch alone, with no other switches, forces a total 
>   refresh of the destination tree.

For more information about the options for Robocopy see this other post I wrote about Robocopy: https://superuser.com/a/566054/144147, which includes external links to more documentation.